# How to share array in php script

Tags: php, arrays

I am beginner of php and mysql I would like to share php array defined in one script, which I want to access from another script here is a scenario

script1.php

```
<?php 
 echo '<html>
       <head></head>
       <body>
       <form action="script2.php" method="post" >
       .......
       ....... some input
       .......
       <button >Submit</button>
       </form>
       </body>
       </html>';
?>
```

script2.php

```
<?php
 ...........
 ...........
 some validation
 $age=array("Peter"=>"21","Ben"=>"45","Joe"=>"33");
 some variable
 $x = 'Peter'; $y= 'Ben';

 // click on button run script3.
 echo " <a href='script3.php?x=$x&y=$y'>
 <button>Submit</button></a>";
?>
```

script3.php

```
<?php

// Though I tried both require_once and include, I can't access array 'age' in script2
require_once('script2.php');
include('script2.php');

// Here I am getting all variable defined in button part in actual code, but can't access array
post_r($_GET);

// Here I want to access array age in script2
?>
```

Please note this is not actual script, but this is a problem I am facing, I have index file in which form is filled once after submit validation is done in second script, if validation is successful then button will appear, as soon as I click on button script3 will activate, here I am able to receive variables defined in script to but I am unable to access array defined in script2 though I tried both together as well individually these functions `require_once` and `include`.

So how to share array ? Kindly someone please give your little time for me, so that I can learn something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script 1

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['key'] = insert_your_array;
```

Script 2

```
session_start();
your_data = $_SESSION['key'];
```

That's it.

`Closing session`

As soon as you finish using `$_SESSION array`, you would close the session. But if you don't close it, then it'll close after `default expiration time` or `browser closes`. Even you can also customize `session time out`.

Function for closing PHP session,
`session_close()`

Comment: when I should close session ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sessions` to access the array in the next page, or use `echo http_build_query($age);` to add it to the link URL or you can put the array in a file and `include` it when needed in different files.

Comment: +1 Thank you so much for your help, your answer also worked but I accepted his since he answered first thank you so much once again